# Get the percentage of bar from bar chart Zipf distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, random

I have a dataset which has 20 columns and 10.000 rows. My plan is to replace some data in my dataset to NaN. I have a task of observing the impact of missing values on my dataset.

My plan is using Zipf distribution to generate the percentage of missing of each column then replace some values to NaN based on those percentages.

For instance, here my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import special

import numpy as np
a = 1.01 # parameter
s = np.random.zipf(a, 200000)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s[s<20], 20, density=True)

plt.show()
```

The bar chart looks like:
[image]

Is that possible to get the percentage of bar, so I can replace some values in each column based on the percentage of the bar? For instance, first column has 80 % missing, second columns 40 %, third 25%, etc.

Comment: Please illustrate what you're trying to do, perhaps by working through the example by hand, showing inputs and outputs. It's not very clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the definition of Zipf distribution. It has been explained quite well on Wikipedia. Here is the picture from Wiki. 
[image]

There are two important parameters which is `a> 1` and `N`. The parameter `a` has an impact to your line (in the figure above `a = s`) and `N` is the size.

When you generate number based on zipf distribution you have to think about frequency. In your code, you used `density=True` that means your bar high is normalized, without using this param you will see exactly count number.

```
column_rank = list(range(1,21))
a = 2.
N = 200000
s = np.random.zipf(a, N)
for i in column_rank: 
    print(i, ((len(s[s==i]))/N)*100)
```

The result:

```
1 60.8245
2 15.265500000000001
3 6.7965
4 3.8015
5 2.4250000000000003
6 1.6760000000000002
7 1.2269999999999999
8 0.9535
9 0.72
10 0.6224999999999999
11 0.4775
12 0.42
13 0.357
14 0.29750000000000004
15 0.24849999999999997
16 0.22999999999999998
17 0.218
18 0.19849999999999998
19 0.1595
20 0.149
```

Plot with exactly number:

```
count, bins = s[s<21], 21
plt.hist(count, bins, align='left')
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 21, 1))
```

The result:

[image]